# The sum of a number and its reciprocal is 5 (1/5) . Find the number.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics, problem-solving

The sum of a number and its reciprocal is 5 (1/5) . Find the number.

I found the answer to be:

x+(1/x)=5(1/5)

(x^2 + 1)/x= 26/5
and so on...

Now, I am trying to figure out how a number multiplied by a fraction could lead to 26 and that would only happen by adding a whole number to the fraction 5+(1/5).

But that is not the case here, right? I don't understand why 5(1/5) is suddenly calculated as 5+(1/5)? What am I missing out on? Thank you in advance for any clarification.

Comment: What does $5(1/5)$ mean? Does it mean $5+\frac15$?

Comment: You can cross-multiply to get $5(x^2 + 1) = 26x$, then solve the resulting quadratic.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig, that doesn't seem to be the difficulty the OP is having.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the question probably looked like this:

> The sum of a number and its reciprocal is $5\frac{1}{5}.$ Find the number.

When writing a positive rational number, one way of doing so is called a "mixed number," where we write the integer part, followed by the fractional part. In this case, while the numbers $5$ and $\frac{1}{5}$ are written next to each other, this is not intended to indicate multiplication, as it would if one or both of them were a variable, but rather, addition. So, $5\frac{1}{5}$ signifies $5+\frac{1}{5}.$

Interestingly, this gives us **one** solution to the problem immediately, because we need to solve the equation $x+\frac{1}{x}=5+\frac{1}{5},$ which clearly has $x=5$ as a solution. On the other hand, we can observe that the substitution $x=\frac{1}{t}$ yields $\frac{1}{t}+t=5+\frac{1}{5},$ or equivalently, $t+\frac{1}{t}=5+\frac{1}{5},$ so $t=5$ is a solution, and so $x=\frac{1}{5}$ is the other solution to the initial equation!

Comment: Thank you truly much for the clarification! So, if it clearly said 5 * 1/5, that would be a whole number multiplied by a fraction. Otherwise 5 (1/5) is just a mixed number that would be calculated as 5+(1/5) as you said.

Comment: @lbti: 5(1/5) isn't a normal or approved  way of writing $ 5\frac15$ I would interpret it as multiplication, as does WolframAlpha.

Comment: @Ibti, if it has parentheses (as you wrote), rather than simply having the two numbers concatenated (as I wrote), then I would interpret it as multiplication, instead. However, if the text instead has $5\frac{1}{5},$ then I *would* interpet it as a "mixed number."

Comment: No, I just can't write the the fraction 1/5 like you on this page so I wrote it with parenthesis. Otherwise it's originally without parentheses, just like you wrote in your answer. But if the fraction is originally in parentheses 5(1/5) it would be interpreted as multiplication?

Comment: @Ibti, if it were written as $5\left(\frac{1}{5}\right),$ then I would interpret it as implicit multiplication, instead, yes. To see how to write things in math mode on this site, you can right click and select "Show Math As->TeX Commands." That will show you what to put between the dollar signs so that other people aren't confused by your posts' typesetting.

Answer (score 1):

$$5\frac12=5+\frac12=\frac{11}2=5.5\neq(5)(\frac12)\left(\text{which is}=5\times0.5=\frac52=2.5\right)$$

Basically, mixed fraction is just a way to write $\frac{11}2$ informing that we need $5$ wholes and a half.

And given sum of number and it's reciprocal as $5\frac15$ then it's quite obvious that one solution is $x=5$ (and the other is $x=\frac 15$). Seen simply by comparing $x+\frac1x=5+\frac15 (\text{or }\frac15 + 5)$.